# python list comprehension :find largest number in sublist using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to find the largest number in a sub list which present in list using list comprehension.

```
max_list = []
max_element = [ max_list:=j  for i in range(len(list1)) 
                             for j in list1[i] if j>max1 ]
```

I want output like [7,6,9] which is largest in each sublist.

This is my input

```
list1 = [[1,7,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the function max() to have the biggest number in a list.
I would solve the problem as follow:

```
for list_num in list1:
        list_max.append(max(list_num))
```

Comment: thanks but i want solution using  list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
lst = [[1,7,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print([max(item) for item in lst])
```

Comment: thanks but i dont want use max inbuilt function

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
list1 = [[1,7,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
max_list = [max(sublist) for sublist in list1]
print(max_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[7, 6, 9]
```

**Explaination:**

in this listcomp we iterate along `list1`, and for each `sublist` we call the `max()` builtin function giving `sublist` as an argument

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but here is a way to find the largest number in a sublist using list comprehension and without **any** built-in function.

This method won't work for Python < 3.8, because using the [`Walrus operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html).

```
list1 = [[1, 7, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
max_list = [[maximum := num for num in sublist[1:] if num > maximum][-1] for sublist in list1 if (maximum := sublist[0]) is not None]
```

**Output:**

```
[7, 6, 9]
```

---

Well it's totally incomprehensible in this format, the alternative without list comprehension would literally be:

```
max_list = []
for sublist in list1:
    if maximum := sublist[0] is not None:
        maximum_list = []
        for num in sublist[1:]:
            if maximum < num:
                maximum = num
            maximum_list.append(maximum)
        max_list.append(maximum_list[-1])
```

---

**Explanation:**

- For each sublist, we compare one by one the numbers with `maximum`. If `num` is greater than `maximum`, then we replace `maximum` by `num` using the Walrus operator.
- This will create a list containing the maximum number encountered since the beginning of the list as it is traversed, like `[1, 7]`. The maximum of the entire list is thus the last one,  with index `-1`.
- However it is necessary to initialize `maximum` before traversing each sublist. To do this, we execute a useless condition: `sublist[0]) is not None`. This condition will always return `True`, regardless of the value of `sublist[0]`. The advantage is that it allows to initialize `maximum` to `sublist[0]`, again thanks to the Walrus operator: `(maximum := sublist[0]) is not None`.
- As the condition is executed before traversing each sublist, instead of traversing the entire list, we can start at the second term: `sublist[1:]`.

---

**Limitations:**

- The list is assumed to contain only sublists with at least two terms.

A modified list comprehension accepting any length of sublist would be as follow (but slower):

```
list1 = [[1, 7, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1], []]
max_list = [[maximum := num if num > maximum else maximum for num in sublist][-1] for sublist in list1 if sublist if (maximum := sublist[0]) is not None]
# [7, 6, 9, 1]
```